# Remove spaces between drawn images on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

When I place a set of images in a canvas, there are empty lines between them:

[image: as seen here,]

And also I noticed that those lines may or may not disappear depending on the zoom level.
Images are `64x64`, they are placed on `Y 0, 32, 64` and subsequently and they are scaled to `32x32`.

Comment: We need to seeing your code to understanding what happen?

Comment: You are properly drawing the images on half pixels resulting in unexpected output: `ctx.drawImage(img, 0.5, 0.5)`

Comment: Check value of `Y` in every row to being right.

Comment: @Mohammad Y Values are correct, they are all multiples of 32

Comment: You can use minor value in `Y`. For example `Y = (i * 32) - 1;`. Maybe helped.

Comment: first thing is to make sure your tiles are ok : draw a single tile on a 64X64 canvas filled by, say, a green background, and check the canvas is  filled by the image.

Comment: There are many reason why this is happening. You will need to show there code and source image for us to find out why, as you should not be getting the seams if done correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of scaling context (canvas.getContext), scale images with fixed width and height.

size = Math.floor(original_img_size * cameraZoom)

for each image:

ctx.drawImage(image, i * size, j * size, size, size);

This way you can avoid trailing spaces in between.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).